# Vertically merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a query regarding merging 4 dataframes 
For example i have 4 dataframes as below :

```
print(df1)

SET I      Violations
Rule 1            1
Rule 2            1
Rule 3            6

print(df2)

SET II       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            3
Rule 3            6

print(df3)

SET III       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            4
Rule 3            8


print(df4)

SET IV       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            5
Rule 3            8
```

My expected output :

```
SET I      Violations
Rule 1            1
Rule 2            1
Rule 3            6


SET II       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            3
Rule 3            6

SET III       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            4
Rule 3            8

SET IV       Violations
Rule 1            2
Rule 2            5
Rule 3            8
```

Outputs i am getting right now :

a)

```
SET I   SET II    SET III   SET IV  Violations
Rule 1                                     1
Rule 2                                     1
Rule 3                                     6 
        Rule 1                             2
        Rule 2                             3
        Rule 3                             6
         Rule 1                    2
                 Rule 2                    4
                 Rule 3                    8
                       Rule 1          2
                           Rule 2          5
                           Rule 3          8
```

command_used:

```
pandas.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```

b)

```
Rule 1  1   Rule 1    2    Rule 1  2      Rule 1  2 
Rule 2  1   Rule 2    3    Rule 2  4      Rule 2  5
Rule 3  6   Rule 3    6    Rule 3  8      Rule 3  8
```

command_used:

```
pandas.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

Please help me with above

Comment: Your expected output is inconsistent - `SET II` is the name for columns, but you want it as a value under another column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the column headings as row values within the final `DataFrame` and a blank row between sets, then you can try [transposing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then transposing back then [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) before using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
s = pd.Series([''] * df1.shape[1], name='blank')

df_new = pd.concat([df.T.reset_index().T.append(s) for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]], ignore_index=True)
df_new.columns = ['SET', 'VIOLATIONS']
print(df_new)

        SET  VIOLATIONS
0     SET I  Violations
1    Rule 1           1
2    Rule 2           1
3    Rule 3           6
4                      
5    SET II  Violations
6    Rule 1           2
7    Rule 2           3
8    Rule 3           6
9                      
10  SET III  Violations
11   Rule 1           2
12   Rule 2           4
13   Rule 3           8
14                     
15   SET IV  Violations
16   Rule 1           2
17   Rule 2           5
18   Rule 3           8
19
```

Otherwise use:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df.set_axis(range(len(s)), axis=1, inplace=False).append(s)
                    for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]], ignore_index=True)
df_new.columns = ['SET', 'VIOLATIONS']
print(df_new)

       SET VIOLATIONS
0   Rule 1          1
1   Rule 2          1
2   Rule 3          6
3                    
4   Rule 1          2
5   Rule 2          3
6   Rule 3          6
7                    
8   Rule 1          2
9   Rule 2          4
10  Rule 3          8
11                   
12  Rule 1          2
13  Rule 2          5
14  Rule 3          8
15
```

#### Edit

To output to an excel workbook without the index, use [`DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df_new.to_excel('./workbookname.xls', index=False)

     SET  VIOLATIONS
       0           1
  Rule 1           1
  Rule 2           1
  Rule 3           6

  SET II  Violations
  Rule 1           2
  Rule 2           3
  Rule 3           6

 SET III  Violations
  Rule 1           2
  Rule 2           4
  Rule 3           8

  SET IV  Violations
  Rule 1           2
  Rule 2           5
  Rule 3           8
```

#### Edit 2:

To add `sum` of violations, list comprehension is not longer viable option. This time we'll use a `for` loop, append results to a list, and `concat` them at the end:

```
df_new = []

for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    total = pd.Series(['Total', df.iloc[:, 1].sum()], name='sum')
    blank = pd.Series(['', ''], name='blank')
    df_new.append(df.T.reset_index().T.append(total).append(blank))

df_new = pd.concat(df_new, ignore_index=True).rename(columns={0:'SET', 1:'VIOLATION'})
df_new.to_excel('./workbookname.xls', index=False)
```

Comment: Chris thanks for your help.It worked but problem is that i want space after every SET and first column of index should not be there..thanks in advance

Comment: @AkashWarkhade updated my answer. Is this what your looking for?

Comment: Yes it worked..But i am converting my final output to sheet of workbook using df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Count')..As we have converted following into string i am not able to convert it into excel..it is giving error "'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'" ..Could you please help to convert it to excel ??

Comment: @AkashWarkhade try using `df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Count', index=False)`

Comment: It worked perfectly..i will required one more help from you.I want wach SET's count Total count should be displayed at end of SET for e.g for SET I, I have values 1 1 6 so total count 8 should be at end of SET 1 in Violations column

Comment: @AkashWarkhade added another solution that should include `sum` of violations

Comment: Chris You are a genius..it also worked perfectly..Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Chris, exception post. I wish I vould give you more than one vote. Akash, good question. Helped to learn a few new things too. Gave each of ur requests a vote too

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this output, is the column names of each `SET` column is different. You have to harmonize these names before using `pd.concat`. Plus in `pd.concat` you are using the wrong `axis`.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for d in dfs:
    d.columns = [col[:3] if 'SET' in col else col for col in d.columns]

df_all = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

Which yields:

```
print(df_all)
       SET  Violations
0   Rule 1           1
1   Rule 2           1
2   Rule 3           6
3   Rule 1           2
4   Rule 2           3
5   Rule 3           6
6   Rule 1           2
7   Rule 2           4
8   Rule 3           8
9   Rule 1           2
10  Rule 2           5
11  Rule 3           8
```